# TeamCity Nuget feed via IIS/ARR/URLRewrite

Tags: iis, arr, teamcity

Versions:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
- TeamCity 7.0.2
- Tomcat 7.0.27
- IIS 7.5
- ARR 2.5
- URL ReWrite 7.2.2

TeamCity is installed into a pre-existing TomCat installation as a JavaEE WAR.
IIS has been successfully setup to reverse proxy calls for TeamCity. My rewrite rule is below:

```
<rule name="TeamCity Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(TeamCity.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

I have no problem logging into TeamCity from a remote host and using/administering it.
However, when I enable the built-in NuGet server, I encounter a frustrating issue.

Trying to access the nuget feed from any remote host proxying through IIS gives me an HTTP 404 error. The 404 error comes from IIS.  When I remove the final path part from the url, the 404 error comes from Tomcat.

Example:

- http://proteus.pointloma.edu/TeamCity/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc from any host gives an provided IIS 404 error.
- http://proteus.pointloma.edu/TeamCity/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/ from any host gives a TomCat 404 Error.
- http://localhost:8080/TeamCity/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc from the server where TeamCity is installed provides the feed correctly.

So, somewhere I am having issues with IIS respecting a redirect with *.svc files, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out why, or where this is set.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the power of posting.  After asking the question, I decided to take a look at the rules I had setup one more time.

The rules were setup on the site level.  I moved them to the server level, and everything works like a charm.

Comment: Adding the rule at server level definitively solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you do not need any rewrite rules. Check TeamCity server context path is the same as in your public server, i.e. http://public.com/**contextPath** and http://localhost:8080/**contextPath**.

TeamCity uses request URI to generate NuGet feed, so you should make sure your proxy provides HOST, X-Forwarded-Host, X-Forwarded-Server, X-Forwarded-For headers. You may enable/check tomcat's access log to see what requests comes from IIS to TeamCity.

Please also take a look at the installation guide at 
http://blog.endjin.com/2010/11/a-step-by-step-guide-to-hosting-teamcity-in-iis-7/

If this does not work, please attach server logs to teamcity-feedback@jetbrains.com

Comment: That definitely resolves the server url issue.

Comment: How do you ensure IIS adds the X-Forwarded.... headers? My NuGet feeds (from Octopus Deploy) are not working, and I am wondering if this is the reason?